# Entity Framework Query for Multiple Tag Cloud related Posts

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, tags, entity

If I have model classes like

```
[Table("MTag")]
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagLabel { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TagRef> RefTags { get; set; }
}

[Table("TagRef")]
public class TagRef
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TagRefId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

[Table("Post")]
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public UserProfile User { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PostGuid { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MTagRef> Tags { get; set; }
    public string ImageFileName { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int ImageWidth { get; set; }
    public int ImageHeight { get; set; }

}
```

What are possible queries to select all matching posts? Can you please give a hint that if I have tags like Car, Mobile how to setup the query?

Comment: Please could you elaborate more *select all matching posts*? the matching in here is based on which conditions?

Comment: I want to select all the Posts matching Tags eg Vehicles or Electronics.

Comment: "Vehicles or Electronics" means what?? Name of tag??

Answer (score 0):

You have tags like Car,Mobile,Vehicles,Electronics and ... .

When you add Post you add some Tag to it.Like this site(Stackoverflow) when you add a Question you add some tags too. Now you want to select All Post with Sepecified tags.

The below Method return All Post that have some tags:

```
public static IQueryable<Post> PostsWithTags(List<int> tagIds)
{
        Context c = new Context();
        var Query = (from Group in c.TagRefs.GroupBy(g => g.TagId) let GroupTags = Group.Select(g => g.TagId) where tagIds.All(gt => GroupTags.Contains(gt)) select Group.Select(g => g.Post).FirstOrDefault());

        return Query ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple hints:

```
var tags = db.Post.Where(m=>m.YourPropertyName == "YourPropertyValue").ToList();
```

Here

```
YourPropertyName = with which property you want to match.

YourPropertyValue = Value of your property.
```